# Crazy basic c++ errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Can anyone explain why Codeblocks is giving me these errors?:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'cout' with no type
error: invalid use of '::'
error: expected ';' before '<<' token
error: '<<x>>' cannot appear in a constant-expression      // <<x>> is many different variable names
```

my code is literally as simple as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myclass.h"

int main(){
   std::string data;
   std::string e;

   e = myclass().run(data);
   std::cout << e << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

what in the world is going on?

EDIT: and yes, i do have iostream. sorry for not putting it there earlier

Comment: When dealing with compiler errors, it is better to solve them one by one from the beginning. In many cases one error will confuse the parser and some later diagnosed errors are not so (I am referring to the `<<x>>` part there, that might refer or not to real errors).

Comment: @calccrypto - about the edit - then show us what does `myclass().run(data)` do

Comment: myclass().run(data) returns a string

Comment: @calccrypto - if you remove (comment) `e = myclass().run(data);` and put a hardcoded string into `e`, does the error still appear ?

Comment: @calccrypto - Show us what `myclass.h` contains. I'm pretty sure the problem is there (you'll see, that if you remove this include, the code will work perfect)

Comment: @calccrypto - then, again, we need to see `myclass.h` :)

Comment: Could it be a problem in "myClass.h"? Could you post that file?

Comment: wow. i figured it out. it was a silly math error that was trying to access array indexes that dont exist

Comment: @calccrypto: If you solved the problem yourself, post the answer and accept it. This is perfectly fine, and helps others with the same problem find the answer quickly.

Comment: its somewhat specific, so i dont think my answer will be useful for anyone else. my description in my previous comment is more useful

Comment: Check if your class definition is terminated by semi-colon

Answer (score 11):

Add

```
#include <iostream>
```

`std::cout` is inside this header

---

EDIT: regarding your edit - this means, that the problem is for sure inside `myclass.h` or there's some code, that is not shown here.

Answer (score 3):

How about `#include <string>`?

Without it (and the following code)

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   std::string data;
   std::string e;

   std::cout << e << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

my g++ reports :

```
tst.cpp: In function `int main()':
tst.cpp:4: undeclared variable `string' (first use here)
tst.cpp:4: parse error before `;'
tst.cpp:5: parse error before `;'
tst.cpp:7: `e' undeclared (first use this function)
tst.cpp:7: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
tst.cpp:7: for each function it appears in.)
```

Answer (score 2):

you should include `<iostream>`

Answer (score 2):

Did you include `<iostream>` somewhere?

**EDIT after knowing that you have added `<iostream>`**

Well you can check:

- `#include <string>`
- If your class definition is finished by semi-colon

If everything is OK I want to check your myclass.h :-(

Answer (score 1):

The code you post (with the EDIT) is correct.  There must be
something funny going on in `myclass.h`.  (Maybe a

```
#define std
```

, so that the compiler sees `::cout`.)

You might want to have a look at the pre-processor output:
compiler option `-E` under Unix, `/E` for Visual Studios.  It
will be voluminous, but all you're interested in is the last 10
or so lines; what the pre-processor has done to your code.